# Syntax error when accessing an array

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have a problem. I've created a class 'Game', and in this class I have an array named 'ShadowField'. This Field contains objects ('Fields'):

```
class Game extends Gameboard
{
    public $ShadowField = array();
    public $GameField = array();
    public $Home = array();

    function __construct($c,$h,$w,$m,$fc){
        parent::__construct($c,$h,$w);

        $counter = 1;
        for($index_h=0; $index_h<11; $index_h++){
            for($index_w=0; $index_w<11; $index_w++){
                array_push($this->ShadowField, new Field(parent::$this, $m, "FF8000", ($h/11.1)*$index_h, ($w/11.15)*$index_w, true, $counter, $index_h, $index_w));
                $counter++;
            }
        }

        $PlayerRed = new PlayerHome($this, $m, "FF0000", 0);
    }
}
```

Then, in my next class, I tried to use this array, but then I got an error:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    parent::__construct($game,$m,$c,$game->ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Top,ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Left);
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\ot\madn\Game.class.php on line 63
```

I don't understand it because it's an array, and I am calling it like an array, so what is the problem?

The "FieldID" is an array, too:

```
class PlayerHome extends Field
{
    public $Color;
    public $Player;

    public $FieldID = array();

    function __construct(Game $game, $m, $c, $p){
        switch($p){
            case 0: array_push($FieldID,1,2,12,13);
            case 1: array_push($FieldID,10,11,21,22);
            case 2: array_push($FieldID,100,101,111,112);
            case 3: array_push($FieldID,109,110,120,121);
            default:echo "Player_$p existiert nicht, bitte eine SpielerID zwischen 0-3 wählen.";
        }
        for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
            parent::__construct($game,$m,$c,$game->ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Top,ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Left);
        }
    }
}
```

(p.s.: Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Mark line `#63` in your code, please

Answer (score 2):

You use it correctly the first time:

```
$game->ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Top
```

However the second time you call ShadowField by itself without referencing the object:

```
ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Left
```

Replace the line in the loop with this (formatted for visibility):

```
parent::__construct($game,
                   $m,
                   $c,
                   $game->ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Top,
                   $game->ShadowField[$FieldID[$i]]->Left);
```